# How to implement sizeof function similar to sizeof operator in c?

Tags: c

I want to implement a custom function similar to sizeof operator in C .  As shown in below code I have a function which is returning size for int datatype.
How can I convert this function into generalize way so it can accept any datatype and return size for passed data type.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sizeof_fun(int a)
{
    return (char *)(&a+1) - (char *)(&a);
}

int main()
{
    int test;
    printf("Sizeof int -> %d \n", sizeof_fun(test));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, you cannot. The necessary type information is not made available to a function. In C++, you could use a template, although I am not willing to assert such a solution would be complete. And even then, the templated function would have to use `sizeof` or something equivalent, such as address arithmetic shenanigans.

Comment: Does it have to be a function, or can it be a function-style macro? (What are you really trying to accomplish?)

Comment: @KenWhite No, I want to try using function instead of funtion macro

Comment: @EricPostpischil.  In function macro it is working so why we can't do using regular function.

Comment: @raj123: Yeah, then you can't do it. C++ template, or preprocessor macros are the only way to do this.

Comment: @raj123: Macros aren't actually functions, they effectively operate as text replacements in the body of the code they're used in, and have access to the same information. Functions have to be called through defined interfaces, which don't allow variable sized arguments in the first place, and lose information from the caller (this is why you can't do `sizeof` tricks with arrays via a function; they can't *receive* arrays, only pointers). This just isn't a job a (C) function is designed for.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  ok . So how does sizeof operator internally implemented in C . Is it implemented as function macro ?

Comment: @raj123 `sizeof`, like `+` or `%`, is an _operator_.  The compiler can implement it with direct code, rather than a function/macro.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. ok got it thanks

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot do this as a C function.**

C function parameters are fixed, and thus you can't have a that dynamically returns different sizes based on the type of parameter. Once inside the function, you don't know the type of the original variable holding the parameter. You would need to either use:

- The real sizeof (why do you need to reimplement that? you can't!)
- Preprocessor macros
- C++ generics/templates
- Function overloading (again, C++)

Comment: Yet the nature of the type, on a limited basis,  can be determine via `_Generic` and passed as an argument.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. It may be that it **is** possible to do this using C11 `_Generic`. Maybe you could post an answer with that?

Comment: @Ángel: It's not actually very interesting; at most it works for a finite number of (pre-known) types you pick in advance, and C has infinitely many possible types.